# Why aren't Collections.checkedMap and friends used more commonly?

Tags: java, collections

I recently stumbled across the Javadoc for the `Collection.checkedMap` family of functions for creating dynamically typesafe views of the standard Collections types.  Considering that they add another layer of safety on top of the collections that diagnoses a relatively common programmer error, I would have figured that they would be more popular.  For some reason, though, in all of the large Java projects I've worked on, I've not seen them used once.

My question is this: is there a particular reason that Java programmers don't use these checked wrappers more frequently?  Or is it just lack of benefit/lack of knowledge of their existence?

**EDIT**: To clarify my question, the generic versions of the collections still contain type-unsafe functions.  `Map`'s `containsKey`, `containsValue`, `remove`, and `get` all operate on `Object`, for example.  My main question is, given this type-unsafety, why more people don't use the checked implementations to diagnose runtime type violations.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

These classes are only really necessary if one is abusing (or not using) generics.  It duplicates at runtime checks that should be sufficient to perform at compile time through the type safety guarantees by the generics engine.

As a result, using these methods is only really interesting in the context of API designers who don't trust the users of the library, and want to protect either themselves, or the users, from the users using the map improperly.

Here's the short of it:  if your code compiles without raw type warnings or any unchecked conversion/type warnings, you are *guaranteed* that the `checked*` methods don't give you any benefit; they are only a runtime hit.

**Edit**

You seem to be concluding that since `remove`, `get`, etc operate on an `Object`, they are somehow type-unsafe.  They are not.  None of those methods will store its operand in the map, so you are certainly not compromising the type safety of the map itself.  Those methods take an Object for one main reason: for backwards compatibility.  There was never any strict requirement that look-ups needed to adhere to the same class.  For example, if an instance of class A and an instance of class B could somehow be equal to each other, putting `a` into the map and then calling `remove(b)` *should* remove `a`'s mapping.

This behaviour needed to be supported once generics were added to preserve backwards compatibility.  Thus they couldn't update the interface to something like `remove(K)` as existing code may rely on being able to remove a mapping given an instance of a completely different class.  It is however not type unsafe, and using the checked version of the map doesn't change this behaviour in the slightest.

Comment: The main reason that it seems like it might be a good idea to have these containers, though, is for things like the Map's .put(), which takes an Object rather than a K (in, for example, a Map<K, V>).  It doesn't really seem like an abuse of generics to accidentally add an object of the wrong type to a Map; that's more a programmer error.

Comment: @templatetypedef: I'm not sure what you mean.  Map's `put` is specified as `put(K, V)`.  You can't put any old object into a Map if you're using generics.

Comment: @Mark Peters- My mistake; I meant `put`, which takes an `Object` rather than a `K`.  `remove` is the same way, as is `containsKey` and `containsValue`.

Comment: @templatetypedef: You said `put` again.  Did you mean `get`?  Anyway, none of those methods you mentioned would actually be affected by using the checked version of the map.  The checks are only done when storing something in the map (i.e. `put`).  Calling `get` on a `CheckedMap` and supplying a non-`K` still won't throw an exception.

Comment: @Mark Peters- D'oh, I meant `get`.  :-)  Also, thanks for a good answer!  That makes a lot of sense, and I'm curious why they designed those wrappers the way they did.

Comment: @templatetypedef: I added a quick blurb about that but I think you've got it figured out now :-).

Comment: the put(K,V) also breaks your "backward compatibility" because the old method doesn't have the constraint. but no, there is no compatibility issues like that, because any code using the generic interface is new code, and they accept the new constraints, and if they can accept put(K,V), they can accept remove(K). actually everybody do want remove(K) instead of remove(Object). now give my point back.

Answer (score 0):

*RETRACT: The following opinion is wrong. There are some good reasons, beyond backward compatibility, why it's better to have lookup index to be of any type.*

There is no divine reason why these methods must take `Object` instead of `E`. In real world programs if a non-E object is passed, it's almost certainly an application bug. The E version API would be better than the Object version in most situations. And I say Sun made a mistake here. There is no backward compatability issue, because the generic API is a brand new API.

Fortunately my IDE (IntelliJ) would warn me if I pass a non-E type to these methods. Static checking has been pushed way beyond what language spec says and what compiler does.

Comment: I didn't d/v, but there IS a backwards compatibility issue, and the generics collections APIs were not "brand new", they retrofitted the existing collections API.

Comment: @mark-peters the put(K,V) also breaks your "backward compatibility" because the old method doesn't have the constraint. but no, there is no compatibility issues like that, because any code using the generic interface is new code, and they accept the new constraints, and if they can accept put(K,V), they can accept remove(K). actually everybody do want remove(K) instead of remove(Object). now give my point back.

Comment: It's not about a source code or bytecode compatibility.  It's about the contract for `remove(Object)` and similar methods.  When they retrofitted the collections with generics, to update `remove(Object)` to `remove(K)` they would have had to change the specification of the method (as in, what it does *functionally*).

Comment: Oh and I agree that `remove(K)` would be a much better design choice were it designed from scratch today, if for no other reason than accepting `remove(Object)` all but implies that having an assymetrical `equals` implementation is OK, when it's not.